PCI Mouse Keyboard and trackpad stop working after few seconds
I've asked this question on redit already, but did not get any help there.
I have a ThinkPad Yoga 1 with Linux Mint installed. Every time after a full reset (battery empty or removed) my mouse and my keyboard disconnects shortly after booting Linux Mint. I can barely log in, and then I have to reboot the device.
Does anyone know, how to debug / fix this issue?
I have the following output from a working boot:
cat /proc/bus/input/devices

I: Bus=001d Vendor=06cb Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Synaptics TM2911-002"
P: Phys=rmi4-00/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/i2c-0/0-002c/rmi4-00/input/input21
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event9
B: PROP=15
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=6f3800001000003

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2  [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=11  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen stylus                 id=12  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen eraser                 id=18  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM2911-002                      id=13  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3  [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=16  [slave  keyboard (3)]

I also did this for a boot, where my devices didn't work and all PCI driven input devices where missing from that list.
I also run dmesq:
dmesg
[...]
[    0.127522] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] (base 0xf8000000)
[    0.127532] PCI: not using MMCONFIG
[    0.127534] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[...]
[    0.162061] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[...]
[    0.179463] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] (base 0xf8000000)
[    0.180360] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] reserved as ACPI motherboard resource
[    0.180377] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.180379] PCI: Using E820 reservations for host bridge windows
[...]
[    0.200414] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform retains control of PCIe features (AE_ERROR)
[    0.201412] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    0.201417] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window]
[    0.201421] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
[    0.201426] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff window]
[    0.201429] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xdfa00000-0xfeafffff window]
[    0.201431] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-3e]
[    0.201454] pci 0000:00:00.0: [8086:0a04] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.201565] pci 0000:00:02.0: [8086:0a16] type 00 class 0x030000
[    0.201578] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0000000-0xf03fffff 64bit]
[    0.201588] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.201595] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x20: [io  0x3000-0x303f]
[    0.201613] pci 0000:00:02.0: BAR 2: assigned to efifb
[    0.201619] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    0.201777] pci 0000:00:03.0: [8086:0a0c] type 00 class 0x040300
[    0.201790] pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0610000-0xf0613fff 64bit]
[    0.201957] pci 0000:00:14.0: [8086:9c31] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    0.201976] pci 0000:00:14.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0600000-0xf060ffff 64bit]
[    0.202043] pci 0000:00:14.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.202206] pci 0000:00:16.0: [8086:9c3a] type 00 class 0x078000
[    0.202227] pci 0000:00:16.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0619000-0xf061901f 64bit]
[    0.202304] pci 0000:00:16.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.202390] pci 0000:00:1b.0: [8086:9c20] type 00 class 0x040300
[    0.202408] pci 0000:00:1b.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0614000-0xf0617fff 64bit]
[    0.202488] pci 0000:00:1b.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.202607] pci 0000:00:1c.0: [8086:9c10] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.202695] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.203310] pci 0000:00:1c.2: [8086:9c14] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.203406] pci 0000:00:1c.2: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.204011] pci 0000:00:1c.3: [8086:9c16] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.204105] pci 0000:00:1c.3: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.204691] pci 0000:00:1d.0: [8086:9c26] type 00 class 0x0c0320
[    0.204712] pci 0000:00:1d.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf061d000-0xf061d3ff]
[    0.204809] pci 0000:00:1d.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.204944] pci 0000:00:1f.0: [8086:9c43] type 00 class 0x060100
[    0.205188] pci 0000:00:1f.2: [8086:9c03] type 00 class 0x010601
[    0.205202] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x10: [io  0x3088-0x308f]
[    0.205211] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x14: [io  0x3094-0x3097]
[    0.205220] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x18: [io  0x3080-0x3087]
[    0.205228] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x1c: [io  0x3090-0x3093]
[    0.205237] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x20: [io  0x3060-0x307f]
[    0.205245] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 0x24: [mem 0xf061c000-0xf061c7ff]
[    0.205286] pci 0000:00:1f.2: PME# supported from D3hot
[    0.205393] pci 0000:00:1f.3: [8086:9c22] type 00 class 0x0c0500
[    0.205411] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0618000-0xf06180ff 64bit]
[    0.205434] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x20: [io  0xefa0-0xefbf]
[    0.205608] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02]
[    0.205738] pci 0000:04:00.0: [8086:08b2] type 00 class 0x028000
[    0.205790] pci 0000:04:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0500000-0xf0501fff 64bit]
[    0.206027] pci 0000:04:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.206375] pci 0000:00:1c.2: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[    0.206382] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0xf0500000-0xf05fffff]
[    0.206468] pci 0000:05:00.0: [10ec:5227] type 00 class 0xff0000
[    0.206492] pci 0000:05:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf0400000-0xf0400fff]
[    0.206648] pci 0000:05:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.206650] pci 0000:05:00.0: PME# supported from D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    0.215178] pci 0000:00:1c.3: PCI bridge to [bus 05]
[    0.215185] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [mem 0xf0400000-0xf04fffff]
[    0.216997] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKA configured for IRQ 0
[    0.217002] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKA disabled
[    0.217096] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKB configured for IRQ 0
[    0.217099] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKB disabled
[    0.217193] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKC configured for IRQ 0
[    0.217195] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKC disabled
[    0.217285] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKD configured for IRQ 0
[    0.217287] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKD disabled
[    0.217377] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKE configured for IRQ 0
[    0.217379] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKE disabled
[    0.217468] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKF configured for IRQ 0
[    0.217469] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKF disabled
[    0.217559] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKG configured for IRQ 0
[    0.217560] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKG disabled
[    0.217650] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKH configured for IRQ 0
[    0.217651] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKH disabled
[...]
[    0.219557] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.220659] PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
[...]
[    0.254863] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02]
[    0.254878] pci 0000:00:1c.2: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[    0.254883] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0xf0500000-0xf05fffff]
[    0.254893] pci 0000:00:1c.3: PCI bridge to [bus 05]
[    0.254898] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [mem 0xf0400000-0xf04fffff]
[    0.254907] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window]
[    0.254910] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 5 [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
[    0.254913] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff window]
[    0.254915] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [mem 0xdfa00000-0xfeafffff window]
[    0.254918] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 1 [mem 0xf0500000-0xf05fffff]
[    0.254920] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 1 [mem 0xf0400000-0xf04fffff]
[    0.255219] pci 0000:00:14.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[    0.255222] pci 0000:00:14.0: PCI INT A: not connected
[    0.255546] PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
[    0.255557] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
[...]
[    0.279282] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    0.280698] ACPI: AC: AC Adapter [AC] (on-line)
[    0.280815] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
[    0.280850] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRB]
[    0.280924] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
[    0.280991] ACPI: button: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    0.281045] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
[    0.281101] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRF]
[    0.281969] ACPI Error: AE_BAD_PARAMETER, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20230331/evregion-300)
[    0.281982] fbcon: Taking over console
[    0.282002] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_TMP]
[    0.282005] No Arguments are initialized for method [_TMP]
[    0.282009] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ01._TMP due to previous error (AE_BAD_PARAMETER) (20230331/psparse-529)
[    0.282079] ACPI Error: AE_BAD_PARAMETER, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20230331/evregion-300)
[    0.282091] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_TMP]
[    0.282094] No Arguments are initialized for method [_TMP]
[    0.282097] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_TZ.TZ01._TMP due to previous error (AE_BAD_PARAMETER) (20230331/psparse-529)
[...]
[    0.356432] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:MOU] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    0.356570] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.356583] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.356599] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
[    0.360542] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: irq 23, io mem 0xf061d000
[    0.364789] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.365022] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.365560] rtc_cmos 00:01: RTC can wake from S4
[    0.365858] rtc_cmos 00:01: registered as rtc0
[    0.365896] rtc_cmos 00:01: setting system clock to 2024-06-26T13:22:23 UTC (1719408143)
[    0.365935] rtc_cmos 00:01: alarms up to one month, y3k, 242 bytes nvram
[    0.365950] i2c_dev: i2c /dev entries driver
[    0.366140] device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
[    0.366157] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    0.366230] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.48.0-ioctl (2023-03-01) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    0.366265] platform eisa.0: Probing EISA bus 0
[    0.366268] platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
[    0.366271] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
[    0.366274] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
[    0.366276] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
[    0.366278] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
[    0.366280] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
[    0.366282] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
[    0.366284] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
[    0.366286] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
[    0.366288] platform eisa.0: EISA: Detected 0 cards
[    0.366299] intel_pstate: Intel P-state driver initializing
[    0.366718] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    0.366754] efifb: probing for efifb
[    0.366777] efifb: showing boot graphics
[    0.367896] efifb: framebuffer at 0xe0000000, using 8100k, total 8100k
[    0.367899] efifb: mode is 1920x1080x32, linelength=7680, pages=1
[    0.367900] efifb: scrolling: redraw
[    0.367901] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[    0.368014] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    0.371449] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    0.371563] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
[    0.372886] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[...]
[    1.454228] hid-generic 0003:0483:91D1.0001: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [STMicroelectronics ST_SENSOR_HUB] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.7/input0
[    1.454749] input: Tablet ISD-V4 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.8/1-1.8:1.0/0003:056A:00EC.0002/input/input5
[    1.455527] input: Tablet ISD-V4 Stylus as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.8/1-1.8:1.0/0003:056A:00EC.0002/input/input6
[    1.455671] input: Tablet ISD-V4 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.8/1-1.8:1.0/0003:056A:00EC.0002/input/input7
[    1.456534] hid-generic 0003:056A:00EC.0002: input,hiddev1,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Tablet ISD-V4] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.8/input0
[    1.556515] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    1.565735] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[    1.565740] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: PCI INT A: no GSI
[    1.565772] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.565778] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.566840] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x100 quirks 0x000000000004b810
[    1.567018] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.567024] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.567028] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[...]
[    1.689857] input: Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.8/1-1.8:1.0/0003:056A:00EC.0002/input/input8
[    1.690172] wacom 0003:056A:00EC.0002: hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Tablet ISD-V4] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.8/input0
[    1.824903] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.920301] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    1.923690] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    1.924132] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    1.924143] ata1.00: ATA-9: SAMSUNG MZ7TE256HMHP-000L7, EXT0BL6Q, max UDMA/133
[    1.924720] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[    1.924734] ata1.00: 500118192 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[    1.926085] ata1.00: Features: Trust Dev-Sleep
[    1.927776] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    1.928133] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    1.928693] ata1.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[    1.929888] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.930354] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      SAMSUNG MZ7TE256 BL6Q PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.931438] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[...]
[    2.265994] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/0003:04F3:0254.0003/input/input11
[    2.266153] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/0003:04F3:0254.0003/input/input12
[    2.266255] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/0003:04F3:0254.0003/input/input13
[    2.266443] hid-generic 0003:04F3:0254.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [ELAN Touchscreen] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
[...]
[    6.234514] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[    6.276336] systemd[1]: systemd 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 running in system mode (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY -P11KIT -QRENCODE +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified)
[    6.276522] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    6.276901] systemd[1]: Hostname set to <XusernameX-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga>.
[    6.278933] Lockdown: systemd: /dev/mem,kmem,port is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[    6.318047] systemd[1]: memfd_create() called without MFD_EXEC or MFD_NOEXEC_SEAL set
[    6.437545] systemd-rc-local-generator[267]: /etc/rc.local is not marked executable, skipping.
[...]
[    6.641841] systemd[1]: modprobe@configfs.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    6.642281] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module configfs.
[    6.642762] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    6.643211] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[    6.645164] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
[    6.649401] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
[    6.650102] systemd[1]: modprobe@fuse.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    6.650581] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module fuse.
[    6.652499] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[    6.656545] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[    6.657439] pstore: Using crash dump compression: deflate
[    6.666441] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted 6c1dfdd1-f021-4413-8800-73f9a019f140 r/w. Quota mode: none.
[    6.670887] systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[    6.674152] pstore: Registered efi_pstore as persistent store backend
[    6.693021] systemd[1]: Activating swap /swapfile...
[    6.694976] systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[    6.696768] systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
[    6.697777] systemd[1]: Finished Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
[    6.698510] systemd[1]: modprobe@efi_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    6.699023] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module efi_pstore.
[    6.700557] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
[    6.710403] Adding 2097148k swap on /swapfile.  Priority:-2 extents:6 across:2260988k SSFS
[    6.710515] systemd[1]: Activated swap /swapfile.
[    6.712096] systemd[1]: Reached target Swaps.
[    6.719678] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    6.722317] systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
[    6.722689] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Complete being skipped.
[    6.732451] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    6.739710] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    6.772809] systemd-journald[279]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[    6.782326] systemd-journald[279]: File /var/log/journal/b76cc7b1bbdc489e93909d2043031de8/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[    7.305064] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    7.319038] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    7.319406] Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    7.321545] Loaded X.509 cert 'wens: 61c038651aabdcf94bd0ac7ff06c7248db18c600'
[    7.365175] spi-nor spi0.0: en25qh64 (8192 Kbytes)
[    7.400521] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/0003:04F3:0254.0003/input/input16
[    7.400668] input: ELAN Touchscreen UNKNOWN as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/0003:04F3:0254.0003/input/input17
[    7.400746] input: ELAN Touchscreen UNKNOWN as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/0003:04F3:0254.0003/input/input18
[    7.400940] hid-multitouch 0003:04F3:0254.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [ELAN Touchscreen] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
[    7.487739] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    7.487771] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    7.487773] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.487778] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.487781] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.487788] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.490087] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    7.495029] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x0, cnv-id 0x0 wfpm id 0x0
[    7.495052] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: PCI dev 08b2/4270, rev=0x144, rfid=0xd55555d5
[    7.506661] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.514463] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    7.521369] Creating 1 MTD partitions on "intel-spi":
[    7.521378] 0x000000000000-0x000000c00000 : "BIOS"
[    7.521382] mtd: partition "BIOS" extends beyond the end of device "intel-spi" -- size truncated to 0x800000
[    7.528413] spi-nor spi0.1: en25qh32 (4096 Kbytes)
[    7.528501] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 4 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
[    7.528506] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
[    7.528509] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
[    7.528511] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-14 Joules
[    7.528513] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules
[    7.768923] audit: type=1400 audit(1719408150.843:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=455 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.768934] audit: type=1400 audit(1719408150.843:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=455 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.768939] audit: type=1400 audit(1719408150.847:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=454 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.768943] audit: type=1400 audit(1719408150.867:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=456 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.768947] audit: type=1400 audit(1719408150.867:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=456 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.768951] audit: type=1400 audit(1719408150.867:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=456 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.768955] audit: type=1400 audit(1719408150.867:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/{,usr/}sbin/dhclient" pid=456 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.768959] audit: type=1400 audit(1719408150.887:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=453 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.768963] audit: type=1400 audit(1719408150.887:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=453 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.808365] audit: type=1400 audit(1719408150.935:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="ubuntu_pro_esm_cache" pid=461 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.010818] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    8.030239] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[    8.030875] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: f8:16:54:29:6d:1e, OTP minor version: 0x0
[    8.099243] usb 2-6: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (0bda:5720)
[    8.112336] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    8.188577] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.26
[    8.188583] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[    8.188585] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS GQET59WW (1.39 ), EC GQHT59WW
[    8.188588] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad S1 Yoga, model 20C0006DGE
[    8.246278] thinkpad_acpi: Tablet mode switch found (type: GMMS), currently in laptop mode
[    8.246291] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[    8.246292] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
[    8.261664] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    8.267063] Bluetooth: hci0: Legacy ROM 2.5 revision 8.0 build 2 week 3 2013
[    8.267942] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[    8.279172] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    8.435041] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel BT fw patch 0x57 completed & activated
[    8.644749] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[    8.838066] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    8.858082] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI EC access misbehaving, disabling thermal sensors access
[    8.882513] thinkpad_acpi: secondary fan control detected & enabled
[    8.925598] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[    8.956063] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0: CX20751/2: BIOS auto-probing.
[    8.956432] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for CX20751/2: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    8.956440] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.956444] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x16/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.956448] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    8.956450] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    8.956453] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:      Internal Mic=0x1a
[    8.956456] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0x19
[    8.980601] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input21
[    8.980735] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input22
[    9.020837] thinkpad_acpi: battery 1 registered (start 0, stop 100, behaviours: 0x7)
[    9.022503] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    9.022509] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    9.022511] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    9.022514] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[    9.037023] ACPI: battery: new extension: ThinkPad Battery Extension
[    9.078133] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input20
[    9.116754] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.116760] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.116764] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.123965] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[    9.157332] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input23
[    9.165227] NET: Registered PF_ALG protocol family
[    9.188713] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input24
[    9.188842] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input25
[    9.297420] Lockdown: Xorg: raw io port access is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[    9.592052] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0
[   11.122971] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   11.122983] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   11.122991] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   11.206206] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[   11.212626] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[   12.840842] wlp4s0: authenticate with 3c:a6:2f:69:af:30
[   12.844287] wlp4s0: send auth to 3c:a6:2f:69:af:30 (try 1/3)
[   14.862112] wlp4s0: send auth to 3c:a6:2f:69:af:30 (try 2/3)
[   14.999878] wlp4s0: authenticate with 3c:a6:2f:69:af:30
[   14.999891] wlp4s0: send auth to 3c:a6:2f:69:af:30 (try 1/3)
[   15.060848] wlp4s0: authenticated
[   15.065001] wlp4s0: associate with 3c:a6:2f:69:af:30 (try 1/3)
[   15.067427] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 3c:a6:2f:69:af:30 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=4)
[   15.069365] wlp4s0: associated
[   15.137184] wlp4s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by 3c:a6:2f:69:af:30
[   60.471943] systemd-journald[279]: File /var/log/journal/b76cc7b1bbdc489e93909d2043031de8/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[   65.924313] Lockdown: fwupd: /dev/mem,kmem,port is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7

I also identified this issue:
[    0.255219] pci 0000:00:14.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[    0.255222] pci 0000:00:14.0: PCI INT A: not connected

But after checking lspci the device looked fine.
How to debug this further?
